# Separate URL for front-end and for back-end

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

I am new to Yii framework.

I have downloaded Yii2, and Yii2 Advanced Application.
I want to create 2 URLs for front and for admin panel.

Front-end URL: `http://localhost/advanced`
Back-end URL: `http://localhost/advanced/admin`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. After downloading the Yii2 advanced template archive. Install the advanced Yii2 using this link [Yii2 advanced installation guide](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/docs/guide/start-installation.md)
2. Follow all the steps in "Preparing application" section of above url.
3. After following all steps you are ready to go. Now you can access frontend and backend i.e 
   For ex:
   FRONTEND: http://localhost/advanced/forntend/web
   BACKEND: http://localhost/advanced/backend/web
4. Create admin panel in yii2 backend. Please follow this url [Backend Admin panel](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/814/guide-how-to-actually-separate-frontend-user-and-backend-admin-on-yii2-advanced/)

I know i am late to answer but i want to help other guys which are new to Yii2. I hope my points will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The url routing subject is quite broad. You should start by reading the detailled documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Basically, you register an `urlManager` component in the application config. In the following example, `front` and `admin` are 2 controllers with an index action.

```
new yii\web\Application([
    ...
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'enableStrictParsing' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false
            'rules' => [
                'advanced' => 'front/index'
                'advanced/admin' => 'admin/index'
            ]
        ],
    ]
    ...
])
```

Comment: means i have to assign controller name statically?

Comment: Yes routing is a static binding between (a set of) urls and (a set of) controllers. But you can pass arguments to your controllers. For example a user id in an url like /users/123 has the same routing that /users/462 with 123 / 462 being an argument.

Comment: how can i make dynamic url for insert/update and delete?

Comment: That's the chapter "named parameters" of the documentation. 
`[
    'posts/<year:\d{4}>/<category>' => 'post/index',
    'posts' => 'post/index',
    'post/<id:\d+>' => 'post/view',
]`

Comment: can you please give me an example or link for that doc?

Comment: The link is in the first line of my answer. There are examples in the documentation.

Comment: but it is not dynamic.. it is static

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81153/discussion-between-mat-and-noddy).

Answer (score 0):

The advanced application template was never designed to do that because it is two separate applications that requires two separate domains (subdomain for 'admin' is fine).

What you want to use instead is [yii2-app-practical-a](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-app-practical-a) which does **exactly** what you want. :)

You have the main application you can access by your main URL - *http://localhost/advanced* and a back-end you can access by the main URL with *admin* appended: *http://localhost/advanced/admin*.